# Calling a function from a factory Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, parameter-passing, angularjs-factory

Relatively new still.  I'm trying to be able to get and set values from a factory, but I can't seem to get a function to run.  It calls a type error.  I also can't add $scope to the factory without it killing it.  Help?

```
app.factory('globals', function() {
    var globalTag = {};
        globalTag.currDrive = "";
        globalTag.myFaults = "";
    var availDrives = "";

    globalTag.currDrive = "this sucks";
    globalTag.myFaults = "I've got a lovely bunch of faulty faults";

    function setDrive(driveID) {
        globalTag.currDrive = driveID;
    };

    return globalTag;
});

app.controller('FaultController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'globals', function($scope, $routeParams, globals) {
    //Setup dummy paramenters
    $scope.driveInfo = {};
    $scope.driveInfo = globals.setDrive("350");
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never expose setDrive methods from the service. Correct code would be:

```
app.factory('globals', function () {
    var globalTag = {};
    globalTag.currDrive = "";
    globalTag.myFaults = "";
    var availDrives = "";

    globalTag.currDrive = "this sucks";
    globalTag.myFaults = "I've got a lovely bunch of faulty faults";

    function setDrive(driveID) {
        globalTag.currDrive = driveID;
    };

    globalTag.setDrive = setDrive; // <--- make it part of globals service API

    return globalTag;
});
```